# Spring Data JPA Property Expressions for a many to many query

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using Spring boot 2, with Spring data & Spring Data JPA, and I'm looking to replace some existing `@Query` methods with Spring Data JPA's [Property Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

However I'm struggling to workout the expression name for a many to many relationship. I'm not too sure if this is possible, as all the example I've seen are based on a one-to-many relationship.

A basic example could be:

**Book Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors", cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

    // Getter and Setters
}
```

**Author Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "forename")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "author_books",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"author_id", "book_id"})
    )
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    // Getter and Setters
}
```

The current SQL query looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM book
LEFT JOIN author_books ON author_books.book_id = book.id
WHERE author_books.author_id = 1;
```

How would you write the equivalent Spring JPA Property Expressions (if possible) within a Book repository?

I've tried the following (with no luck):

```
List<Book> findByBooks_AuthorId(Long authorId);
List<Book> findByBooks_Author_Id(Long authorId);
List<Book> findByBooks_AuthorsId(Long authorId);
List<Book> findByBooks_Authors_Id(Long authorId);
```

One solution would be to obtain the author object by it's id, and then calling `author.getBooks()`. However, I would like to be able to provide filtering and pagination of results using the spring data `PageRequest` and `Specification` classes.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to find books by author's ID. So you need to write it as the method's name:

```
List<Book> findByAuthorsId(Long id);
```

That's it! 
Also it is unnecessary to use *@Column*(name=...) annotation if the target column's name is the same as entity field's name.
[Property expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using Query Annotation..
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM book LEFT JOIN author_books ON author_books.book_id = book.id WHERE author_books.author_id = ?1")
List<Book> findByBooks_AuthorId(Long authorId);
```

Comment: You clearly haven't read my question, I stated that I was looking to **replace my existing** `@Query` annotations.

Comment: yes, i might have missed the statement while reading.. but unfortunately, we don't have direct method to get it.. the only alternate is to override the method in a repository class..

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
List<Book> findAllByAuthorId(Author author);
```